# Computing PageRank

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm following the book here to compute PageRank scores: http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/markov-chains-1.html

I built the transition matrix P as indicated in the book. Then I computed the PageRank scores by raising the transition matrix P to higher powers, as said in the book. To make sure my computations are correct I followed this example: http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/the-pagerank-computation-1.html

The transition matrix is: 
P = np.array([ [1./6, 2./3, 1./6], 
               [5./12, 1./6, 5./12],
               [1./6, 2./3, 1./6]  ])

The results of the PageRank scores are the following (by computing P^40):

```
[0.28, 0.44, 0.28]
```

as in the book.

But the book also says that one can find the PageRank scores by computing the principal left eigenvector of the transition matrix P. So I tried this with numpy:

```
v, V = np.linalg.eig(P.T)
left_vec = V[:, 0].T
print left_vec
```

and I got:

```
[-0.46829291 -0.74926865 -0.46829291]
```

so what's wrong?!

Comment: Nothing is wrong. Normalize the eigenvector such that the sum of its entries is $1$.

Comment: @PavelJiranek but the eigenvector values are negatives?! How to do that then!

Comment: Add its entries and divide. Scalar (non-zero) multiple of an eigenvector is an eigenvector.

Comment: I believe that Python has something like `left_vec /= sum(left_vec)`.

Comment: @PavelJiranek ok this was correct, it gave the correct answer. But I'm wondering why we had to do this? It's not mentioned in the book!

Comment: Eigenvectors are not unique, but eigenspaces are. Linear algebra books certainly mention that in some form.

Comment: @PavelJiranek so what we computed at the end was an eigenspace?

Comment: Ok, so assume that the eigenvalue (in this case $=1$), is simple. Then the eigenvector is determined *up to a non-zero scalar multiple*. So whatever scalar you multiply that vector with, you still get an eigenvector ($Ax=\lambda x\;\Rightarrow\;A(\alpha x)=\lambda(\alpha x)$). In your application, entries of that eigenvector are positive and sum to one, but the eigenvalue solver (`np.linalg.eig`) does not know that. So it's up to you to normalize that eigenvector such that its entries sum to one.